# Responsive Image in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

what is the best way to create responsive image using css, I'm basically trying to switch the header image when screen is (max-width: 480px) this is the code i have

```
<div id="header">
<img src="images/H550xW1250.png" alt="img" width="100%" class="size1280"/>
<img src="images/H683xW480.png" alt="img" width="100%" class="size480"/>
</div>

<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.size1280 {
    display: none !important;
}
.size480 {
    display: block !important;
}
}
<style/>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Im just asking is this a good way to do ? or is there a better way ?

Comment: This works just fine, I would avoid using `!important` unless it is absolutely necessary

Comment: It didn't work for some reason without using !important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in Julian B's post, the `picture` element is made to do this sort of thing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/

It lets the browser check the media query and choose the best image file to display. Here's how it might look in your HTML:

```
<div id="header">    
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 480px) srcset="images/H550xW1250.png">
    <img src="images/H683xW480.png" alt="header image">
  </picture>
</div>
```

The code above displays the smaller image by default, but the larger image when the browser width is larger than 480px. You can add more `src` elements if you have more image sizes to toggle.

Note that I'm using a `min-width` query rather than `max-width`. This means browsers that don't understand the picture element will display the small image by default.

You can see in the [support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture) for `picture` that it's supported by most modern browsers. If you need to fully support older IE, there are [polyfills](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) available.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. both of the images show at the same time no matter what is the browser size.
can you add another image to the code, one is 480px W the other one is 1200px W?

Thank you

Comment: @Abdal - Apologies. The `src` tag should have been `source`. I've corrected it above. Here's a demo of how it should work: [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/nwalton3/pen/PKmBJv?editors=1000)

Answer (score 2):

How about using the picture tag I think this would be much easier. Like this

```
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 480px)" srcset="imgsrc">
   <img src="imgsrc">
</picture>
```

Comment: can you explain please!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing things mostly correctly, but you are not considering the default styling of the elements. In your case, the only styling you care about is `display` to be `none` or `block` accordingly.

So consider the following example, it does exactly what you want to achieve. The only difference is that I had to add a little extra styling for my images `width` and `height`; as well as having to use my own images to represent the example. All you need to do is click on *view fullscreen*, shrink the browser screen, and watch the magic happen.

What is going on then? I know that the default `display` attribute will be: `block` meaning it is visible. But then I let the media query take care of modifying the display to `none` when the width of the screen reaches a certain point. This helps avoid the use of `important` since there is nothing to override. I make sure I separate it too, simply because it is easier to read and understand what is going on.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .size1280 {
      display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  .size480 {
      display: none;
  }
}

.size1280 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.size480 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150?text=1280" alt="img" class="size1280"/>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150?text=480" alt="img" class="size480"/>
</div>
```